# Java print to file from multiple methods with appending the text

Tags: java, text, printing

I want to write a small program with a few methods and I'd like to be able to print different things from different methods into an output file. How can I print from every method outside of main, into the same file appending after the last line. I'm also open to other methods than `PrintWriter`.

```
package tennisoddssimulator;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class TennisOddsSimulator {

    private static final int TOTALMATCHES = 1000;
    private boolean bestOf5Sets;
    private boolean P2ToServe;

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws
            FileNotFoundException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {

        PrintWriter writer
                = new PrintWriter("output.txt", "UTF-8");

        for (int i = 0; i < TOTALMATCHES; i++) {

        }
        writer.close();
    }

    public static void printMatchNo(int matchNo) {
        /*I want to print the number
        of the match currently being
        simulated from this method by
        calling this method after the
        start of every match*/
    }

    public static void printGameScore() {
        /*I want to print the current
        game score from this method by
        calling this method after every
        point has scored in a match*/
    }

    public static void furtherMethodForPrinting1() {
        /*You've probably got the
        idea by now*/
    }

    public static void furtherMethodForPrinting2() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend opening up a fresh `PrintWriter` in each helper method, e.g.

```
public static void printMatchNo(int matchNo) {
    try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output.txt", true); // append mode
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF8");
        PrintWriter pwFile = new PrintWriter(writer);
        pwFile.write("The match number is: " + matchNo);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (pwFile != null) {
            pwFile.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I recommend this approach is that it probably doesn't make sense to keep a `PrintWriter` perpetually open in your program.  Rather, you should just open one, write, and then close, when you need to.

By the way, if you are just doing this for informational purposes, you might want to look into using one of the logging frameworks available for Java.  Once configured, you would just need to make a simple method call to write to the log file.

Comment: When I call this method isn't it going to overwrite the original output text file every time instead of appending it?

Comment: @sasieightynine You're right, and I've updated my answer.  It's a bit of code to open a `PrintWriter` in append mode for a UTF-8 file.

Comment: It's still not working the way I'd expect, I want to be able to print into a common output file with all of the methods. Currently if I print with a method then with another one, I can only see in the output file what the last method has written into it.

Comment: @sasieightynine I had a typo in my answer.  It should work now.